# Is it possible to install 14.04 with 1gB flash stick?

Tags: system-installation

Ok, I would like to install ubuntu 14.04. I have 1 gB flash stick and am unable to make it bootable with unetbootin, because I need like extra 5 mB. Is there anyway that I can install by not using wubi method or dvds?
What about downloading 12.04 and upgrading it to 14.04? It is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is network installation media available for download that should fit on that thumb drive.  You can download it here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/14.04/

Basically this is a minimal image that you can put on a thumb drive, and then once you start the installation process it downloads the rest of the setup from the internet.

When you go to the URL above, just select your architecture (probably amd64) and then download the "mini.iso" file and use that image with unetbootin.  The installer is text based, but is pretty straight forward.  Hope this helps, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either way, it works. Remember though, you still may need some room for persistence mode. The 12.10 to 14.04 may be safer for the drive, though it may be a slower process. And you might use LinuxLive.